# Passing unix c language parameters and argument values

Tags: c, parameters, parameter-passing

First of all, I understand that I used Google Translator as I am not proficient in English.

You have to implement several commands as an assignment

Since the basic syntax of the c language is not familiar, we have implemented "ls", "pwd", and "quit (exit)" that do not pass argument values so far.

Now you need to implement functions that require arguments and parameters, such as "cd" and "mkdir".

The method used so far when each command is input is as follows.

```
-- main
 if(strncmp(cBuf, "exit", 4) == 0) 
            break; 
        else if(strncmp(cBuf, "ls", 2) == 0)
        cmd_ls();
        else if(strncmp(cBuf, "pwd", 3) == 0)
        cmd_pwd();  
        else if(strncmp(cBuf, "cd", 2) == 0)
        cmd_cd(argc);
        // else if(strncmp(cBuf, "cat", 3) == 0) 
        // cmd_cat(argc, argv[1]); --> ERROR CODE


-- cmd_cat() definition
void cmd_cat(int argc, char *argv[]){
...
}
```

Until now, when a command was entered with the strncmp function, strings were compared and solved, but from now on, they are commands that need to pass argument values.

What if I want to pass the value (command) following the "cd" and "cat" commands to the "cmd_cd" or "cmd_cat" function?

```
ex) 
case cd) cd /myshell
case mkdir) mkdir myshell
```

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

**Edit 1) The question code. **

```
#define ERROR       (-1)

-- func cmd_cd
void cmd_cd(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *path;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        path = argv[1];
    }

    else if((path = (char*)getenv("HOME")) == NULL)
    {
        path = ".";
    }

    if(chdir(path) == ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: bad directory.\n", path);
    }
}


-- func main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    char cBuf[MAX];

    while(1) { 
        printf(">> "); 
        fgets(cBuf, MAX, stdin);

        if(strncmp(cBuf, "exit", 4) == 0) 
            break; 
        else if(strncmp(cBuf, "ls", 2) == 0)
        cmd_ls();
        else if(strncmp(cBuf, "pwd", 3) == 0)
        cmd_pwd();  
        else if(strncmp(cBuf, "cd", 2) == 0)
        cmd_cd(argc, argv);
    }
}
```

**Output result**

```
$ ./myshell 
>> cd
>> pwd
/home/test_work/
>> cd ./myshell (Directory already created)
>> pwd
/home/test_work
```

Comment: `ERROR CODE` What error exactly are you getting? `cmd_cat` is defined to accept a `char *argv[]` but you are passing in a `char *`. Pass in `argv` instead or `argv[1]`.

Comment: When changing to argv[1] -> argv, the error code disappears, but the value of argv is not passed.

The changes are as follows.

void cmd_cd(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
...
     else if(strncmp(cBuf, "cd", 2) == 0)
cmd_cd(argc, argv);
...
}


If I want to go to the directory of cd ./myshell, is it possible to implement it with the syntax I used (strncmp or function)?

Comment: I am not familiar with stackoverflow and do not know how to handle the code, so readability is poor. I am really sorry..

Comment: I'm not sure what "the value of argv is not passed" means. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64381073/edit) the question with the code and include the exact error or incorrect behaviour.

Comment: "the value of argv is not passed" means that if i type cd ./myshell command, ./myshell is not recognized.

Stackoverflow is inexperienced. How do you use the edit code....?

Help manual says'code', isn't it...? Thank you very much for your consideration.

Comment: You need to describe things in terms of the code. What does "not recognised" mean? What exactly happens in the code? Click the "edit" link I gave you and update with any new code and exact behaviour.

Comment: Added all the code related to the question.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger. Look at the `argv` values. Is it what you expect? Your code is fundamentally wrong. `argv` are the args to your program when it is first started. But what you want is to extract the arguments from the `stdin` input which is stored in `cBuf`. A common way to do the parsing is with `strtok`.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for finding the direction

You also learned how to ask questions when using stackoverflow in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: You should consider what to do about the extra arguments if you are given more than one argument to `cd` — for example, `cd / home/user`.  You should probably error out.